# Extend PackageManager Implementing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, interface, sharedpreferences

I Need Access to PackageManager and SharedPreferences from a plane Java Class (No Activity).

I tried extend the Class PackageManager and implement the Interface SharedPreferences like following:

```
public abstract class TestClass extends PackageManager implements SharedPreferences {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Do code here

}
```

Isn't now my class not something like sharedPreferences?
Now I don't Need to create a new Object of the Class SharedPreferences? But wait. I'm implementing an Interface and not a class? Can I really create a Instance of an Interface? I don't think so. I think the whole Interface-Story are a real big interrogation mark for me.

How can I get Access to SharedPreferences in my plain class?

```
public abstract class TestClass extends PackageManager implements SharedPreferences {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.getSharedPreferences(...); // Doesn't work
}
```

What i'm doing wrong, how does it really work? It would be really nice if someone can explain my issue in simple words. Thanks in advance :)

**Update**

I don't have Access to an activity-context! Sorry, forgot to say that. The plane Java class is called from my appWidget Long time before one of my activities are getting created.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `SharedPreferences` in a non-activity class, you can use Context for that.

Like:

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(Context context){
        SharedPreferences sPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", null);
    }
}
```

You don't need to extend `PackageManager`, implement `SharedPreferences` etc.

You can also access `PackageManager` using Context:

```
context.getPackageManager();
```

When you create object of this class, yo would need to pass context like:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @MysticMagic, thank you for the respond. I Know that, sorry that i forgot to say that.. But, my plane class is called from my appWidget Long time before one of my activity starts. Therefore i don't have a context except the appwidget context. Do you understand my issue? :)

Comment: or is the context from the appWidget the applicationcontext? because the appwidget is declared in the manifest under the tags `<application>...</application>` ?

Comment: I didn't work with app widget, but can't you use that context?

Comment: ok, tried it. I can get the applicationcontext from the appwidget context. Now i can create an anonymous inside my appwidget class. But i wanted to send the context to a non-anonymous class from my appwidget... but i think you are the wrong Person to ask something like that. But thank you for your time ! :) I'll give you upvote